# Jquery Datatable Error: $ is not a function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

here is the bundle config

```
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/datatable").Include(                   
                    "~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js",
                    "~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"                       
                  ));



        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"
                 ));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"
                  ));
    }
}
```

And here is the _layout

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatable")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Here is the  javascript

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#productTable").DataTable();
});
```

please help me. i just cant figure out why i keep having this error. it seems like it is an issue with referencing the Datatable libs. 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please use @section scripts in your view.

```
@section scripts
{
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#productTable").DataTable();
    });
</script>
}
```